# Applet: Loading image in jar file that is not in home directory

Tags: java, html, jar, applet

this title may sound confusing so I'll explain my problem.
I am converting my java application to an applet, and it works fine in Eclipse and when I make a html file with  tags. But when I upload my applet to [google sites](https://sites.google.com/site/projectteagame/tea.jar) and execute it via a html file, the program itself loads fine, but it tries to load its images from my own hard disk instead of from the JAR file. How can I change that?

HTML:

```
<applet
archive="https://sites.google.com/site/projectteagame/tea.jar"
code="ymte.core.Loader"
width=300
height=300> </applet>
```

Edit:

I keep all my files in the jar, for speed and ease. My code to obtain the images is:

`img = ImageIO.read(Loader.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/object/ball.bmp"));`

This works in my IDE, but not in the online use

Comment: *"all my files in the jar, for speed and ease"* Does not gel with *"tries to load its images from my own hard disk"*.  `getResource`  would only look on your hard disk if the HD was on the run-time class-path of the applet.  Since the run-time class-path of the applet is `tea.jar`, it should be looking there.

Comment: I ran my applet from a html-file, so I think its classpath is in the same folder as the html-file. But I added an archive-tag to the html-file.

Comment: *"I think its classpath is in the same folder as the html-file."*  Not with that HTML, but I already mentioned that.  What is the URL of the HTML?

Comment: img = ImageIO.read(Loader.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/object/ball.bmp"));  will work if you change it to Loader.class.getResourceAsStream("ball.bmp"); and put your ball.bmp at the same package as your Loader class.

Comment: BTW - please use the [cross-compilation options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#crosscomp-options) when compiling code using the Java 7 SDK!  I could test the applet locally if it was compiled for 1.6 or lower.  :(

Answer (score -1):

You can provide your code to tell us how you obtain the image, but I suppose it is not bundled in the jar. A way to do that is to put the jar in your packages and obtain it like this:

> Class.getResourceAsStream("foo");

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

This is kinda gimmicky, however. A preferred way would be to put your image into a directory in your project that is outside your sources, something like images or resources and then bundle it in the jar of the applet. Use your favorite build tool (ant, maven, ivy) to include the image in the jar. Directory structure can be like this:

```
project
-src
-resources
 -<yourImage>
```

Then you would access your image as a URL or File using a relative path. If you provide more code, maybe you can receive further help.

***EDIT:***
SInce your resource is in your applet, you can put it in one of your packages. Then, further in your code you can do

```
Class.getResourceAsStream
```

and that is how you can get your image, since it is guaranteed to be in your classpath.

Basically, if you have a package structure like this:

> project   src
>       com.foo.bar
>       com.foo.bar.stuff
>       com.foo.bar.resources
>          -yourImage
>          -otherStuff
>          -ResourceGetter.java

You can do the following in your ResourceGetter

> `Class.getResourceAsStream("yourImage");`

Which will give you a handle to your image and you can load it as you would do normally.

Comment: *"File using a relative path"*  `File` and `Applet` do not mix, unless loading something off the local file-system of the end user & the applet is signed and trusted.  Then, a relative path is meaningless.

Comment: If the applet extracts the file, File and Applet do mix, since the File is located at the local file system. Also, he might try to load it from a predefined place on the internet. By the way, what do you mean by 'do not mix, unless..' and 'Then, a relative path is meaningless'? Sounds to me like you are confused.

Comment: The JRE extracts the classes, the applet does no such thing. *"Also, he might try to load it from a predefined place on the internet."* No `File` object in an applet will **ever** point at *any* resource on the internet. *"Sounds to me like you are confused."*  How many applets have you developed?

Comment: Jnlp has long been the standard in developing applets. JNLP descriptors are an easy and structured way to deploy any Java application to your client. With Java Web Start it is easy to define a resource and your applet will automatically download for your client to a directory of the developer's choosing. Sounds to me that you are unfamiliar with the standards in deploying an applet. Take a look at this lesson: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jnlp-136707.html

Comment: What the heck do you think this has to do with JNLP?!?  (And yes, I'm fully aware that applets in a Plug-In2 JRE can be deployed embedded using JWS, as I mentioned in the info pages for [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) & [Applet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info).  1) But this applet is *not* being deployed by JWS (that much is obvious from the applet element). 2) Being deployed by JWS would change nothing in terms of access to the `java.io.File` class, or it's inapplicability to being used for application resources.  I have no more time for this nonsense.  -1

Comment: Depending on the java.policy and if the applet is signed or not, File can freely access all resources that are on the client machine. Since he can DEPLOY the image on the client machine with NO problem, we end up having an image at a known location that can be accessed with no problem. I think you are seeing a problem where there is not. Check this, for example: http://www.smaxe.com/applet.jsf?id=rtmp-desktop-publisher-svc1. This applet downloads A BUNCH of .dlls to the client machine to a known location and then accesses them using File. How is that a problem?